# UIScrollView + UIImageView zoom in/out

Tags: zooming, scrollview, multi-touch

I have UIScrollView contains 3*UIImageView, each UIImageView has an image.
Code I used:

```
scrollView.delegate = self;

[self.scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];

scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.75;

scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

NSUInteger nimages = 0;
CGFloat cx = 0;
for (; ; nimages++) {
  NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg", (nimages + 1)];

  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

  if (image == nil) {
    break;
  }

  imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];        
  CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
  rect.size.height = image.size.height;
  rect.size.width = image.size.width;
  rect.origin.x = ((scrollView.frame.size.width - image.size.width) / 2) + cx;
  rect.origin.y = ((scrollView.frame.size.height - image.size.height) / 2);
  [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(cx, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

  [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
  [imageView release];

  cx += scrollView.frame.size.width;
}

[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(cx, [scrollView bounds].size.height)];
```

How can I make ScrollView zoom-able using multi-touch?
I used this code:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return imageView;
}
```

But it didn't work correctly, images got overlapped, because ScrollView contains multiple images.

How can I fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't add the image views to the scrollview directly, instead, do it this way:

Make a new UIScrollView object for each UIImageView separately and set the frame to be the same with the image view. Add the image view to the scrollview as a subview. Remember, these scroll view objects are used to zoom the images only, so set the zoomScale, minimumZoomScale and maximumZoomScale, also set the scroll delegate. In the delegate controller:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
return [scrollView.subViews objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Then, add all the scroll view objects to the scroll view you used in your code. This scroll view is used only to scroll the sub scrollviews created above.

Got the idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PinchGesture to your image views... 
There is no need of 3 scrollviews to be used.

Answer (score 0):

try this for your 3 images:

```
**.h Controller:**

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController{

IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView; 
UIImageView *imageView;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;
```

**.m Controller:**

```
@synthesize scrollView, imageView;


-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollVi­ew *)scrollView{ 

return imageView;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImageName.png"]]; 
self.imageView = tempImageView; 
[tempImageView release]; 
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0; 
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.6; 
scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES; 
scrollView.delegate = self; 
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
}
```

This code worked for me :)